# Why ASP.NET Core application can't take data form MSSQL database when is hosted by full IIS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I'm now learning ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to make sample of single web application. I'm using MVC and Entity Framework. I have HomeController with two actions:

- home/index <- here I'm returning View with AngularJS (my SPA)
- home/getdata <- here I placed function with HttpPost Action, that returns JSON data form MS SqlServer

I published website to the filesystem folder. When I run it by IIS Express form cmd everything works fine, but when i'm trying host it by full IIS it's not: I still have a proper redirecting to the views but taking data form DB is not possible.

Connection string i putted here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      var connection = @"MY CONNECTION STRING";
      services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

I have a problem with IIS configuration as suppose.

Any advices?

Comment: What exception and/or another message do you get? What is expected and what does it actually do?

Comment: If you use integrated security to connect the database, make sure the user configured in IIS has the right permissions

Comment: Please enable detailed logs in the server and see the error, we may isolate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kevin, I solved my issue.

I think, that my problem was in my connection string. I want to connect with SQL Server Authentication, but i put in connection string: User ID, Password and unfortunately "Integrated Security=True".

In that case Windows Authentication was used and User ID and Passoword was ignored.

I just removed "Integrated Security=True" from connection string. Now it's works.

SQL Server have mixed authentication and is on my PC... probably when I run IIS Express it have my account rights, so with this "bad" connection string still worked fine.